# how to create view from 3 linked tables starting from data to another table

Tags: mysql

In my db I've 4 table.

```
tb_main (id_c)
tb_r (id_r, desc_r)
tb_p (id_p, id_r, desc_p)
tb_c (id_c, id_p, desc_c)
```

the table tb_r is "linked" with table tb_p by field id_r.

the table tb_p is "linked" with table tb_c by field id_p.

the table tb_main have a id_c field that is the same of tb_c.

I'd like to create a view (test) starting from the tb_main field id_c

The test view should have this data

```
test ( id_c, desc_c, id_p, desc_p, id_r, desc_r)
```

I have done only the first step

```
SELECT  tb_main.id_c,
FROM    tb_main
JOIN tb_c ON tb_main.id_c = tb_c.id_c
```

It's possible to do? how could I do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start from tb_main  try this

```
SELECT tb_c.id_c AS id_c, desc_c, tb_p.id_p AS id_p, desc_p, 
       tb_r.id_r AS id_r, desc_r 
FROM tb_main 
INNER JOIN tb_c  ON tb_main.id_c  = tb_c.id_c  
INNER JOIN tb_p ON tb_c.id_p = tb_p.id_p 
INNER JOIN tb_r ON tb_r.id_r = tb_p.id_r
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (You can use Inner/Right/Left joins based on your needs):

```
SELECT tb_c.id_c AS id_c, desc_c, tb_p.id_p AS id_p, desc_p,
       tb_r.id_r AS id_r, desc_r
FROM tb_c  
INNER JOIN tb_p ON tb_c.id_p = tb_p.id_p
INNER JOIN tb_r ON tb_r.id_r = tb_p.id_r
```

Comment: the data that I get with your scripts are ok, just that I would like starting from main table id_c data. it's possible to do? or do I have another view?